# @CrossOrigin doesn't work for all methods within controller class, net::ERR_FAILED also returns

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, controller, cors, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am using react as FE and Spring for the BE services. I have a controller class with several different methods (mainly POST and GET) and have annotated it with @CrossOrigin. When authenticating the user, it works just fine and the method is available, however all other methods return CORS error.
Errors I receive is:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9002/users/simpleUser/1,function%20()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
UserService.jsx:38 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:9002/users/simpleUser/1,function%20()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D net::ERR_FAILED
```

My controller class is as follows:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;
    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @GetMapping("/simpleUser/{id}")
    public AppUser getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId) {
        return this.userService.getSimpleUser(userId);
    }


    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<AppUser> getAllUsers() {
        return this.userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public JwtResponse authenticate(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
--some logic here--
}
```

Authenticate method which is POST works, however all other ones return the error

I have tried annotating the methods with

`@CrossOrigin(value="*")`

and the class with `@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600, methods = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})`
however none of those works.
I have also tried adding cors in the security config

`@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { http.cors().and()...`

but this doesn't work either. Anyone that can help?

react code for fetching is:

```
 async getUser(userId, token) {
    return await fetch(`${USER_ENDPOINTS.GET_USER}/${userId}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }).then(async (response) => {
      const userGot = await response.json();
      console.log("user:" + userGot);
      return userGot;
    });
  }
```

**Edit**:
fixed it, the problem was adding cors to the security configuration AFTER authenticated antMatchers

```
http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(""/users/save")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .cors().and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: I think you need to configure ```cors``` correctly on your BE, in nodeJs for example you need to install cors and use it like this ```app.use(cors());```, in laravel you need to pass the routes to the ```cors.php``` if you are building an api, but idk about spring-boot.

Comment: You need to allow request header `Authorization` in your CORS configuration.